# Is there any way to simulate a user input when running a bat file from java?

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to test the working of a bat file through junit. For most cases I am able to invoke and get the response codes. But there is a case where the user has to give a manual input to the terminal to proceed. Is there any way to simulate the input or any work around for this ?

Note :  I cannot change the actual code to accept command line parameters as input.

I use process builder to invoke my bat file
Sample snippet :-

```
File dir = new File("E:\\test");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "Start","test.bat");
        pb.directory(dir);
        Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show your existing Java code in case it's required for an answer.

Comment: `System.setIn(...)` and on batch level `... <myfile.txt`.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder.redirectInput`

Comment: While you can use java to do that, there are other solutions out there written specifically to do such kind of things, for example [tag:expect].

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `pb.redirectInput()` to obtain the input stream of the process, then write into that stream the data that the user would enter if the process was running interactively.

For documentation and example code, see:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html